# How to convert a string into source code in C

Tags: c

I want to design such a progam which will read the string and then conver it into C source code then, it will be compiled and executed directly. This means reading the string at runtime  compiling the string source code into machine code and then execute it directly. Is there any way I can do this in C because i am not getting any references about this topic. 
Thanks in advance..

Comment: what java is doing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using gcc and on linux
thy this method

Read the souce code and write it to a .c file,

using 
`system("gcc file.c");
system("./a.out");`
do compilation and execution

Answer (score 0):

Can you use bash?

```
~$ ./progExe < inputFile.txt > newProgram.c && gcc newProgram.c -Wall && ./a.out
```

Answer (score 0):

```
1 : execute your program
2 : take string from user according to your requirement
3 : create a new file
4 : write string in to file
5 : save file as .java extension
6 : compile the new file
```